# how to make geocodes from two array lists in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geocode

Hey Guys I have four integer array lists which were created after parsing a json file:

```
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("posts");
    o = a.getJSONObject(0);
    c = a.getJSONObject(1);
    lat.add((int) (o.getDouble("Latitude")* 1E6));
    lng.add((int) (o.getDouble("lontitude")* 1E6));
    lat1.add((int) (c.getDouble("Latitude")* 1E6));
    lon1.add((int) (c.getDouble("lontitude")* 1E6));
```

In the long run I would like to loop through these lists to get all the longitude and latitude values, but for now I am getting the 1st two values. My problem is that the application force closes and I think their is something wrong when I create the geocodes:

```
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint( (int) lat.get(1), (int) lng.get(1));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
    GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint((int) lat1.get(1), (int) lon1.get(1));
    OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point1, "", "");
```

If anyone could knows what im doing wrong it would be a great help thanks

Comment: *"My problem is that the application force closes (...)"*. First step would be to check in LogCat what the actual error is and go from there. Since you already posted a question here, you might as well add the stacktrace of the error. Also, any particular reason you're casting lat/long to ints? That's potentially a huge loss in precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double latiude[] = null;
double longitude[] = null;
 JSONObject  json=JSONFunction.getJSONfromURL(Url);
 try{ 
    JSONArray  JArray = json.getJSONArray("results");  
      latitude = new double[jArray.length/size()];
      longitude = new double[jArray.length/size()];
      Log.v(TAG, "getting results"); 
    for(int i=0;i<JArray.length();i++)
     {
            JSONObject e = JArray.getJSONObject(i); 
            JSONObject location1=e.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");  
            latitude[i]=location1.getDouble("lat"); 
            longitude[i]=location1.getDouble("lng"); 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was mixing up my variable names, stupid mistake on my part. For my solution I created 3 vectors, one vector of geopoints and two other vectors. One for latitudes
and another for lontitudes.

```
        o = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("posts");
    int arrSize = a.length();
        points = new Vector <GeoPoint>();
    lat = new Vector<Integer>(a.length());
    lng = new Vector<Integer>(a.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {

        o = a.getJSONObject(i);
        lat.add((int) (o.getDouble("Latitude")* 1E6));
        lng.add((int) (o.getDouble("lontitude")* 1E6)); 
        points.add(new GeoPoint( (int) lat.get(i), (int) lng.get(i)));
        overlayitem = new OverlayItem((GeoPoint) points.get(i), "", "");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapController.animateTo((GeoPoint) points.get(i));
        mapController.setZoom(6);


    }
```